DNS netmask ordering in non-Microsoft platforms
I have an internal Docker host that has many IP addresses, one for each of its container networks. Something like this:
;; ANSWER SECTION:
host.lan.internal.  900 IN  A   172.29.0.1
host.lan.internal.  900 IN  A   172.29.4.1
host.lan.internal.  900 IN  A   172.29.8.1
host.lan.internal.  900 IN  A   172.29.12.1
host.lan.internal.  900 IN  A   172.29.16.1
host.lan.internal.  900 IN  A   172.29.20.1
host.lan.internal.  900 IN  A   172.29.36.1
host.lan.internal.  900 IN  A   10.0.3.1
host.lan.internal.  900 IN  A   10.0.5.1
host.lan.internal.  900 IN  A   10.0.7.1
host.lan.internal.  900 IN  A   10.10.10.1
host.lan.internal.  900 IN  A   172.29.24.1

The objective here is to implement something similar to Microsoft's DNS netmask ordering (ref #1, ref #2), where a DNS client only receives responses to A queries that are "closer" to it, but preferably using Unbound, or maybe dnsmasq or bind9.
Note: this is needed for DNS queries outside the Docker context/host.
Do we have any major DNS server implementation on Linux that supports netmask ordering or local subnet prioritization?

BIND9 supports this. Or did, rather, as the sortlist feature was removed a week ago and won't exist in the upcoming v9.22.
A better approach might be to remove all those addresses from DNS and replace them with a single OSPF-routed 'loopback' address representing the server.
